# DB2 database activation is very slow

Tags: performance, db2-luw

we have a db2 11.1.4.4 database on centos 7, file system format is xfs and the size of database is 50 TB. Sometimes it takes too long time (1-2 hours) to activate the database, instance memory usage at the time when the activate command is running is less than 10 percents of its configured value, disk I/O is ok and there is no message in db2diag.log and server log, what causes this problem?

edited:
Our database is HADR and sometimes when we have stopped the database and we want to activate it, we encounter this problem on both of primary and standby.

Thanks

Comment: Open a Case with IBM support. They will tell you how to collect necessary db2 trace to investigate the problem.

Comment: also I suspect that you are omitting the relevant facts that would give a clue. Such as when this symptom started, what the HA configuration is, whether the database was shutdown cleanly, whether large rollback jobs are running, whether index rebuilds are happening, and whether any operating-system messages are happening, and whether IPC resources are adequate.  So: for a 50TB database, either up your game, or pay IBM-support for help.

Comment: I would suspect you are not stopping cleanly and sometimes you have many logs to rollforward through. That is the only thing I can think of that could potentially take hours on activation. Check the diag.log

Answer (score 0):

Too many primary log files could slow down your DB activation as well.